# Getting touch location info from a container while allowing views in container to respond to those touches

Tags: swift, swiftui, gesture

In SwiftUI, I have a container view that I want to have capture touch locations but then allow views inside the container to still respond to those taps. Using .simultaneousGesture gets me part of the way there, but many built-in SwiftUI controls won't respond to touches from inside the container. Below is an example of what I've tried so far:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var sliderVal = 0.0
    @State private var rectVal = CGPoint.zero
    @State private var lastTouch = CGPoint.zero
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            VStack(spacing: 50) {
                Slider(value: $sliderVal, in: 1...20)
                
                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                        .fill(.mint)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                                .onChanged { value in
                                    rectVal = value.location
                                }
                        )
                    
                    Text(String(format: "%.2f %.2f", rectVal.x, rectVal.y))
                        .disabled(true)
                }
                
                Button("Hit me!") {
                    print("I'm hit! \(sliderVal), \(lastTouch)")
                }
                
                Text("Tap test")
                    .padding()
                    .background(.teal)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("Text was tapped")
                    }
            }
            
        }
        .simultaneousGesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
                .onChanged { value in
                    lastTouch = value.location
                }, including: GestureMask.all
        )
    }
}
```

All of the views except for the slider work as expected, but the slider doesn't respond at all. I've tried making my own slider control and it works just fine but this is part of a package that would need to be able to wrap arbitrary content, and I've found at least one other SwiftUI control that doesn't work here (Picker, both .segmented and .wheel, the default picker style actually does work though). I've tried using UIViewRepresentable to make a touch layer to place over the content, but his blocks all touches from going through even with userInteractionEnabled = false. I can make my package work without this but I'll lose some functionality. Any help is appriciated!

Edit:
I tried changing the DragGesture to a TapGesture, and the slider works. However, I don't know how to get location information from the TapGesture, so it doesn't solve the problem unfortunately.

Edit 2:
I added `including: GestureMask.all` to the simultaneousGesture modifier but this didn't affect anything.